# Handling special (turkish) characters when writing PDF using Zend drawtext

Tags: php, pdf, drawtext, zend-pdf

I am using drawText of Zend PDF to write to PDF files. I am not able to write certain characters despite using encoding.

```
$page->drawText('González '.' '.' Memişoğlu', 192, 600, $encoding);
```

I've tried several different types of encoding but none prints 'Memişoğlu' properly. 'González' works fine with UTF-8.

These are the results (what is printed in the PDF) for each encoding type I've tried

Windows-1254 - MemiÅŸoÄŸlu

Windows-1250 - MemioÄlu

Windows-1252 - MemiÅŸoÄŸlu

UTF-8 - Memiolu

What kind of encoding should I use, or is there another step to print the characters properly in the PDF?

Thanks.

EDIT: My pdf is written using Helvetica, so it possible that these characters are not available in the font.

Comment: Are you sure those characters are available in your currently selected font? If they are, specify *how* your text is printed "incorrectly". In reverse? Upside down? In another size?

Comment: I'll have to check if the characters are available. I don't understand what you mean by 'specify how your text is printed "incorrectly"'. I gave examples of what is printed for each type of encoding I used.

Comment: Helvetica doesn't know how to print those characters. You'll need another font. Try the open source font FreeSans. It looks almost exactly the same as Helvetica.